# Pathfinding on large, mostly walkable, non-grid based maps

Tags: path-finding

I am developing a 2D space RTS game which involves spaceships navigating over large maps (think Homeworld but in 2D), which mostly consist of open space, but occasionally containing asteroid fields, space structures and other unwalkable terrain elements.

The problem I have is that using a grid-based solution with a good enough precision results in a very large amount of nodes, so pathfinding takes a long time, and considering that maps contain a lot of open space, huge walkable sections of map are represented by large amount of walkable nodes.

I have tried switching to a quad-tree representation of the map to reduce the amount of nodes in a navigation graph, but this approach yields wierd paths that involve ships going through the exact center of the square when in fact it has to just go through the square to the next one.

I have managed to implement a path optimization which removes nodes from the path when there is a straight path to a next point in the path, but this only partially resolved the problem, so the feeling I have now is that I am still using wrong representation for my navigation graph.

Looking at the way Unity does things, there is a way to represent navigation data using a mesh, but I haven't found any source code or even any more or less derailed description of its inner workings.

So which data structure/pathfinding algorithm is optimal for my case?

Comment: The class of algorithms you're looking for is known as [any-angle path finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Any-angle_path_planning#References)

Comment: I managed to dig up some explanations on the topic of visibility graph. Trying to implement that.